# Cannot access groupBy data Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Inside method I have a list that contains **grouped data**:

```
var listofData = _context.DBONE.where(x => x.Id==3 && x.Status!=0)
                  .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Class })
                  .Select(q => new { Result = q.ToList() }).ToList();

if (methodParam == 10) 
    {
      data = listofData.Where(x => FunctionCheck(---CANNOT ACCESS THE FIELDS FROM GROUP DATA TO PASS AS PARAMETERS---) == 10).ToList();
    }
```

And this is the function that will receive 2 parameter from the **grouped data**:

```
private int FunctionCheck(int id, string name)
        {...}
```

But, I **cannot access the desired field** inside 'listofData'. I can access only in case the listofData is **not** using groupBy().

Comment: wll, how **do** you try to access that data? Please show where you call the `FunctionToCheck` and how you provide the params. Furthermore your class-structure would be pretty helpful

Comment: @Valkyrie_30 You should be able to call x.Result without problems

Comment: @moozywu yes I did. But then I had to use FirstOrDefault() to access the required fields which later showed **Error CS1662**

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] which would include all types and some data as valid C# code?

Comment: @Valkyrie_30 you have to use `FirstOrDefault()` because `x.Result` in `listofData.Where(x => FunctionCheck(...))` is a list. You defined it as a list in `Select(q => new { Result = q.ToList() })`. In query syntax, were you expecting `data = from d in listOfData from item in d.Result where FunctionCheck(item.Id, item.Name) select item;`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you are able to access your data but you are actually creating a "list of a list"

Watch my example, I think I have reproduced your scenario here:
[image]

As you can see, I then have a "result" which contains a list of users where Id == 3. The problem is that you create a new anonymous object with a props that is a list. So if you try the last thing you see in my image above, I think you will be able to access your rows.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that after your GroupBy call, the result is of a grouping type - every item of your list is an Enumerable of the original item, so you would have to operate on that grouping in a following manner:

```
// Groups such that all items in that group pass your check
listofData
    .Where(group => group.All(item => FunctionCheck(item.Id, item.Name) == 10))
    .ToList();

// Groups where at least one item matches
listofData
    .Where(group => group.Any(item => FunctionCheck(item.Id, item.Name) == 10))
    .ToList();
```

The desired outcome is not really clear from the question but this is the step you are likely missing.

Another approach which might be potentially useful is pre-filter the colleciton of items before grouping them:

```
var listOfGroupedDatas = _context.DBONE
  .Where(x => x.Id ==3 && x.Status != 0 && FunctionCheck(item.Id, item.Name) == 10)
  .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Class })
  .ToList(); 
// This will result in a list of groupings in which all items pass your check
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to call SelectMany to project into one dimensional array.

```
var listofData = _context.DBONE.where(x => x.Id==3 && x.Status!=0)
                  .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Class })
                  .SelectMany(q => q.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: It is pretty weird to group the initial collection to then just flatten it out right after, don't you find?